# Power automate Flow - Extract information from invoices - get value from keyValuePairs

Tags: power-automate, flow, powerapp, azure, power-platform

How to get values from array with `Compose`action?

I will try `Azure Cognitive Service` - `Extract information from invoices`. There is an Array called `keyValuePairs`.

How I can get to single values ?

1. Initialize variable - varArray
2. Set Variable keyValuePairs - output:

   ```
    [
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.expando",
    "key": "Number",
    "value": "20230002",
    "confidence": 0.907,
    "keyLocation": {
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.expando",
    "page": 1,
    "boundingBox": {
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.expando",
    "left": 0.5104732920061759,
    "top": 0.1300018790827594,
    "width": 0.11190841384289363,
    "height": 0.009177612878252667,
    "polygon": {
   ```

`Compose action`

```
variable('varArray')?['key']?['Number']?['value']
```

`Error`

> Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Compose' inputs at line '0' and column '0': 'The template function 'variable' is not defined or not valid.'.

Comment: If you want to get value from first object in array, try: `first(variables('varArray'))?['key']` for key and `first(variables('varArray'))?['value']` for value. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get value from *first object* in array output, use:

**For key**:

```
first(variables('varArray'))?['key']
```

**For value**:

```
first(variables('varArray'))?['value']
```

---

Or you can use **Apply to each** action with array output and inside loop, you can use expressions like:

**For key**:

```
item()?['key']
```

**For value**:

```
item()?['value']
```

Comment: What if i want exactly value from key number? And this value isn't first. My goal get return this ''''20230002''''

Comment: Check 2nd approach in my answer > You can use Apply to each, user array as input to apply to each > Inside apply to each action, you can add compose action and use expression like: `item()?['value']`

Comment: Can you share example of data with multiple items in the array to understand the data and suggest better expression?

Comment: Yea apply to each, but i no need all keys just one key with name number, can be item?('key'=='number') assign like this?

Comment: Inside Apply to each > Add "Condition" > use condition like: `item()?['key']` is equal to Number > Then inside "If yes" block of condition, use compose action as mentioned above.